# In static fluid, pressure at same heights are equal. Is this applicable to the oceans?

Tags: fluid-statics

Generally we consider the reference as horizontal line. But if we consider a vertical water column in the ocean. Then, if we want to consider the reference it should be a circular not a horizontal line, so that we get equal pressures at equal heights.

Comment: Reference for what? How course depth from surface has to be used ib the oceanic case. Keeping in mind salinity (density) for very precise assertions. And earth rotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is generally true but only to a first approximation.  There are tides which mean that the shape of the surface of the ocean is actually something complicated.  The Earth is rotating which means that nothing is spherical.  There are also atmospheric pressure effects and wind which can make significant differences to the surface of the oceans.  There are differences in temperature which make things yet more complicated.  Finally as a result of most of the previous effects there are large currents which make things yet *more* complicated.

So it's true to a simple-minded physicist's approximation (if I wanted to know what kind of diving suit I'd need to go $1\,\mathrm{km}$ down it would be a good enough approximation I think) but in real life things are hugely complicated.